# Anchors in a HTML-Object in GWT

Tags: html, gwt, anchor

I'm writing a Webpage in GWT and I use the following structure: I have a VerticalPanel as navigationmenu containing some gwt-buttons. Then I have a VerticalPanel as a contentPanel where different HTML-Pages could be loaded into (via ClientBundle).
The contentPane contains a single gwt-HTML-Object for that, in which the HTML-File is loaded.
Now I have some buttons in the navigationmenu, I'd like to use like HTML anchors in the contentPanel. Is that possible?
So when a longer HTML-File is loaded into the contentPanel and I perform a click on one of these buttons, that the page jumps to the specific anchor in the HTML-Object.
Any ideas how to realize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think there should be two solutions:

If you use Anchor widgets or plain html anchor's in the navigation menu you can do it just like with regular html:

**Navigation menu**:
`<a href='#myAnchor'>`

If you really want to use GWT-Buttons you probably have to use [Window.Location](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Location.html). Something like this might work tough I haven't tried it myself:

```
button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
         Window.Location.assign('#myAnchor');
    }
});
```

Alternatively you could set the id of the Anchor's in your contentPanel `<a id='myAnchor'>` and use following function to scroll to the anchor.

```
Element elem = DOM.getElementById('myAnchor');
    if (elem != null) {
        elem.scrollIntoView();
    }
```

I recommend the first approach.

Comment: thank you ... the idea with the DOM was what I was looking for :)